# Delete, wait and see or leave?

Tags: discussion

Wanting to undo tmux breakout pane I've searched for answer, found it, but as it seemingly addressed a similar problem and didn't work for me I asked my own question. Turns out, I should've read deeper, or change perspectives and read, as when few folks kindly pointed out my question was a dupe, I re-read the question they pointed to and found one remark, that in the end was crucial to the answer.

So, my question has the answer there. It is a dupe. I'm now wondering, if I'd found it without being pointed that my question is a duplicate. So, for obvious bias, I'm turning here for an answer.

My tmux question: [Bring a broken out pane back to window in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309241/bring-a-broken-out-pane-back-to-window-in-tmux)

I'm pondering: **DELETE**, leave for two weeks and see if anybody has that problem, then leave or delete, leave. Advice from other members is welcome.

Comment: Why would you delete?

Comment: @terdon to not clutter the site, was my reasoning. Also, I cannot rule out that my thinking of "let's leave it and see" is just a result of "don't delete my question, it's mine, so it's surely useful" bias. :-)

Comment: Sure, and thanks for asking! Just think of duplicates as sign posts showing the way to the answer. The next user with the same problem might find your question first (depending on how they search) so having it around can help us direct this user to the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Leave it alone. Duplicates are useful for the site since they help other users find the right answer. There is absolutely no reason to delete your question and very good reason not to.

So do nothing. You have your answer, the question is correctly marked as a duplicate and all is well with the world :)

Comment: Why delete? Because I don't like getting down-votes

Comment: @Jodes and why would you get downvotes? You have exactly one question on the site and, while it has indeed been closed as a dupe, it has no downvotes and even has an upvote.

Comment: Firstly, who's to say it doesn't apply to others? Secondly, I am on other SE sites and know how prolific down-vote trolls are. I'm not having a go at your answer (that would be ridiculously ironic) but just trying to highlight the awkwardness of the reality

Comment: @Jodes Fair enough, sorry I thought you were referring to something specific. Bear in mind though that, unlike so, this community doesn't often down vote dupes. Not unless it's such a blatant dupe that a ten second search would have found it anyway.

Comment: No, I should apologise, I was confrontational. True - it happen on more sites than just SO in my experience, although it is one of the worst. I'm firmly in the camp of thinking that the SE system is quite broken and needs tweaking

Answer (score 5):

I agree with terdon, but since you said:

> ...I re-read the question they pointed to and found **one remark, that in the end was crucial to the answer.**

I'll add that it would be a very good idea to specify which one remark that was, *somewhere.*

You could put a comment on the answer that helped, quoting the important line and emphasizing its importance.

Or you could put a comment on your question, linking directly to the answer that helped and specifying which was the crucial sentence (by quoting it in your comment).

Knowing which is the *important* sentence of the answer is a useful addition to the community's knowledge.  And knowing its relevance to your duplicate question (by a comment on your question) would enhance your question's value as a sign board pointing to the right answer.

---

(And of course, if that one important remark was in a comment, *not* in an answer, then put it in an answer!  Comments are temporary.)

Comment: That I did. :-) I wanted to highlight why the linked question didn't work for me (what caused me to disregard it) and figured perhaps others will have similar problem so marked it up in a comment. Thank you for verifying that that was a good idea on my part. <bows>